# How do I live monitor on linux what files get accessed created modified and deleted?

Tags: filesystems, logging, monitoring, watch

How do I monitor from this moment on what files get accessed / modified / created / deleted. (in live mode), similar to fseventer / fslogger?

Comment: Now I changed the title, as I'm interested about the process, not to shop anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On unix system you can use inotify-tools, built on top of [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) kernel subsystem API.

By [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) you can have live mode monitoring on standard output:

```
inotifywait -m -r -e access -e modify -e create -e delete --format 'PATH:%w%f EVENTS:%,e' {{path_to_monitor}}
```

Notes:

- **-m**: monitor indefinitely
- **-r**: recursive monitor
- **-e**: specify file system events to be monitored
- **--format**: specify the output of the command

Example (command performed on monitored directory followed by realtime inotifywait output):

```
$ cd {{path_to_monitor}}
$ touch test
PATH:./test EVENTS:CREATE
$ rm test
PATH:./test EVENTS:DELETE
```